# List specific elements of an array in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have an array something like this,
array=( A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
I would like to list values “b, e, o, u, z”
I tried using:

```
`echo ${array[1,4,14, 20, 25]}`
```

**[This command doesn’t work]**
The output be: B E O U Z
I’m not looking for

```
echo ${array[1] array[4] array [14]...}
```

What would be the perfect command to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a way without `eval`:

```
#! /bin/bash
array=( A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z )
x=(\${array[{1,4,14,20,25}]})
eval echo ${x[@]}
```

Comment: sligthly better `eval  a=\( \"\${array[{1,4,14,20,25}]}\" \); echo "${a[@]}"`

Comment: Did I stumble into a code golf challenge? What's wrong with plain old `printf "%s " ${array[1]} ${array[4]} ${array[14]} ${array[20]} ${array[25]}` ?

Comment: otherwise without eval `x=(); for i in 1 4 14 20 25; do x+=( "${array[i]}" ); done; echo "${x[@]}"`

Comment: @MikeHolt, the question is more about array slicing than golfing, and seems you missed the double quotes, and how do you handle an arbitrary list of indices

Comment: Easy enough to handle an arbitrary list of indices without using `eval`. I'm not in the "eval is evil, don't ever use it" camp (although the warnings about security are not without merit), but in this case it seems at best it saves you a slight amount of typing. Your own `for` loop example is plenty concise, and much clearer than the `eval` solution. Using `eval` just seems IMO like being needlessly clever. Not to mention the `for` loop will handle arbitrary lists of indices just fine.